# Unioning each 4-elements group in grid using postgis

Tags: postgis, gdal, union

I have a table containing multipolygons of stratasystems. One of the stratas contains a set of multipolygons - each of equal size - so they make up a grid of non-overlapping polygons. This grid is too detailed - we want to reduce the resolution by combining each 4 gridcells into a new cell and taking the mean of the data value in the 4 cells being unioned.

Is there a way to do this in postgis or using a gdal tool? The grid is bound around a coastline - so some cells will not have 3 neighbours - so they should be unioned with 2 or 1 neighbour if possible.

Edit: Here is sample data input:
Query:`select id, name, ST_AsText(geoshape) from hcell where id_grid=9 and (name='Y0X0' or name='Y0X1' or name='Y1X0' or name='Y1X1')`

```
|id | id_grid | st_astext | name |
|---|---------|-----------|------|
|1036243|Y0X0|MULTIPOLYGON(((12.840605 64.22435,13.32486 64.305214,13.145422 64.51621,12.657933 64.43471,12.840605 64.22435)))|
|1036323|Y0X1|MULTIPOLYGON(((13.32486 64.305214,13.811942 64.38435,13.635805 64.595985,13.145422 64.51621,13.32486 64.305214)))|
|1036244|Y1X0|MULTIPOLYGON(((12.657933 64.43471,13.145422 64.51621,12.962985 64.72692,12.472228 64.64476,12.657933 64.43471)))|
|1036324|Y1X1|MULTIPOLYGON(((13.145422 64.51621,13.635805 64.595985,13.456705 64.80734,12.962985 64.72692,13.145422 64.51621)))|
```

and desired output:
Query`select ST_AsText(ST_Union(geoshape)) from hcell where id_grid=9 and (name='Y0X0' or name='Y0X1' or name='Y1X0' or name='Y1X1')` 
Output:

```
|st_astext|
|---------|
|POLYGON((13.32486 64.305214,12.840605 64.22435,12.657933 64.43471,12.472228 64.64476,12.962985 64.72692,13.456705 64.80734,13.635805 64.595985,13.811942 64.38435,13.32486 64.305214))|
```

Comment: Sample data and desired output?

Comment: @EvanCarroll - ive added sample output to the question.